# Why do I need to learn ReactJS before NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, user-interface, next.js

Learned TS and have to pick a framework.

Can someone please explain to me why we have to learn ReactJS BEFORE NextJS? All the articles advice of this but no one ever goes into WHY.

Can't I just learn NextJS and build UI elements with that? Or do we use react UI elements in our NextJS app and add routing to the ReactJS components via NextJS? Is this how it works? Or am I missing something...

If we use ReactJS UI elements in NextJS, I should spend my learning curve with ReactJS simply building UI elements I want for my site, then when I am comfortable with react. Try to couple them in a NextJS project, correct?

Edit: Let me clarify. What part of React CANNOT BE DONE IN NEXT. That we NEED to learn React for? I already know that React does CSR and Next can do SSR/SSG.

Comment: Because NextJs is a framework built on top of the ReactJs library.

Comment: What does this mean? Do I use react elements in Next or can I build elements using Next??

Answer (score 4):

Because NextJS covers some advanced topics like Server-Side-Rendering, API routes, and page routing. Without knowing React you might learn NextJS but it will be painful probably. Also, most of the documents and videos out there assume that you know React so you may consider this too. I think it is like learning Typescript without knowing Javascript.